# MacOS tkinter application compiled with pyinstaller opens and immediately closes

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I wrote a python app using tkinter for the gui and compiled it using pyinstaller, but when you try to open the app created by pyinstaller it opens and closes immediately and doesn't say anything. The executable works perfectly, but no matter how you open the app, with `open` in terminal or double-clicking it from finder, it can't open.

I've also tried it with py2app and nuitka and the executables they create work fine, but no matter what I do the application instantly closes when I open it.

To compile, I ran `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --hidden-import tkinter [python file]`.

I am running python 3.8.1 on MacOS.

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could help, I've been struggling with this for too many hours now.

Comment: which version of macos? check if security settings is coming in between?

Comment: Maybe it is a fault in your code, post some of it, so its easier to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround on a [github page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820#issuecomment-489502526).
It makes the app a little slow to open because it needs to open two apps, but it works when nothing else did.